# Saving a text description to a CSV in one row at the time - Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Good day everyone. I am trying to get a product description and save it to a CSV file. The problem is that the description has a lot of <.br> tags and when writing to CSV it does not save it to one cell. Is there a way I can scrape the description and save it to one cell below the other. This is only part of the code, what I am trying to achieve to scrape the title, description, price and SKU number to a CSV file in one row. Here is my code, and I apologize if the code is a mess, I am a self taught coder. Thank you in advance.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs-extra');


function delay(time) {
return new Promise(function(resolve) { 
    setTimeout(resolve, time)
});
}


(async function main(){
 try {

    const urls = [" https://www.comet.hr/bosch-dij-busilica-gdb-350-we-0601189900-proizvod-4021/",
    " https://www.comet.hr/bosch-aku-busgsr-18v-ec-te-18v-2x5ah-ma-55-uni-06019c8006-proizvod-4024/",
    " https://www.comet.hr/einhell-tc-cd-aku-busilica-solo-alat-18-35-4513927-proizvod-8036/",
    ]

await fs.writeFile('busilice.csv','description\n');


for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {

    const url = urls[i];
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless:false, 
        userDataDir: "./user_data", 
        executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'});

   
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(`${url}`, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    await delay(3000);
    

    const description = await page.evaluate(
        () => document.querySelector('.cd-tab-content').innerText.trim()
        );


    

    await fs.appendFile('busilice.csv',`"${description}"\n`);
        


    await browser.close();

   }

   console.log('finished');


 } catch(e){
console.log('sjebao si',e);
}
 })();
```

Answer (score 0):

use regex to replace any character in a given unicode range with its html entity equivalent. The code would look something like this:

```
//your variable
const description = await page.evaluate(
    () => document.querySelector('.cd-tab-content').innerText.trim()
);

//remove \n chars and convert them to <br>
let removedNewLines = description.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');

//convert html tags to html entity
let encodedDescription = removedNewLines.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/g, function(i) {
     return '&#'+i.charCodeAt(0)+';';
});
    
console.log("ENCODED DESCRIPTION:",encodedDescription);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Yeah, 'opis' is my description, should have translated that, my bad. I tried with regex, but still it saves the description to multiple cells instead of one.

Comment: I think there are `\n` new line characters in your description like `\n` . If yes, you should eliminate them. Temporary convert \n chars to `<br>` than apply my solution. Also can you share an example description in your question. I try to understand that content.

Comment: I thought that \n would write the description in a new row for each url. Will try you suggestion. You can check the example of the description here ("Opis proizvoda"): https://www.comet.hr/bosch-aku-busgsr-18v-ec-te-18v-2x5ah-ma-55-uni-06019c8006-proizvod-4024/

Comment: Thank you hakiko, I really appreciate you effort to help me. I tried the above code, and it seemed to work (although another problem came with regex because I need characters like č,ć,š and so on, and I end up with  "5.0Ah&#60;br&#62;1"). When I added other elements to the code (title, SKU, price, img_url)  with the description I ended up with a mess again in the CSV. I tried removing \n from fs.write and I gives me new rows but when I remove it from fs.appendFile it saves the items in the new cell.